# Construct a 2 x 2 matrix with elements i + j using R. how do I write this in code?

Tags: r, matrix

i badly need help idk what this is-

```
matrix (c (1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), nrow= 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

idk if this is right

Comment: You're giving 6 numbers `c(1,2,1,2,2,2)`, and putting them into to a 2x2 matrix, filling across the rows. You only get the first 4 of the 6 numbers included in the matrix since you hard coded 2 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: Are you trying to use a set of 4 i's and 4 j's to populate a 2x2 matrix? If so, you you offer code that creates an example with the `i`-values, the `j`-values and the numbers you wnat to appear in the matrix entries for those indices.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to see what's happening if you replace the numbers with letters, e.g.

```
matrix(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), nrow= 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,] "A"  "B" 
#> [2,] "C"  "D"
```

Basically, you are filling up a 2X2 matrix 'by row' and the last two elements in your vector are excluded. If you change your dimensions you can include all of the elements in the vector:

```
matrix(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), nrow= 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,] "A"  "B" 
#> [2,] "C"  "D" 
#> [3,] "E"  "F" 

matrix(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), nrow= 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
#> [2,] "D"  "E"  "F"
```

### Edit

I think I've figured out what you are trying to ask - based on your title you want to fill a matrix using "i + j" (i.e. a nested for loop). Here is a potential solution:

```
vector_of_letters <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

mymatrix <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
count <- 0
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:2) {
    count <- count + 1
    mymatrix[i, j] <- vector_of_letters[count]
  }
}
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,] "A"  "B" 
#> [2,] "C"  "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a matrix that looks like this:

```
|1   2|
|1   2|
```

In this example R fills numbers by row from the concatenated list of numbers until it runs out of space. In this case each row has 2 element with only 2 rows total meaning that R will drop the last 2 numbers.

---

**Update:** Answer to your comment

```
matrix (c ((1 + 1)^2/2, (1 + 2)^2/2, (2 + 1)^2/2, (2 + 2)^2/2), nrow= 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

**Output:**

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  2.0  4.5
[2,]  4.5  8.0
```

Comment: I tried # r - indicates as row
# c- indicates as column

r1c1 <- (1 + 1)^2/2
r1c2 <- (1 + 2)^2/2
r2c1 <- (2 + 1)^2/2
r2c2 <- (2 + 2)^2/2
matrix(c(r1c1, r1c2, r2c1, r2c2), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

how do I simplify it to lessen the r2c2 <- (2 + 2)^2/2
we need it in numbers not on letters.

Comment: @raeyu does the update answer your question?

Comment: I think not, i need to simplify it to make the code clean